# How to enable connection pooling with spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc-postgresql

I have a Spring Boot application with data-r2dbc dependency. I use PostgreSQL as DB.
So I already have in place the following dependencies (gradle notation):

- `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc:2.3.5.RELEASE`
- `io.r2dbc:r2dbc-postgresql`

I need to enable connection pooling for R2DBC connections.
Unfortunately, I could not find any exhaustive manual to do so.

According to this quite outdated [release notes](https://spring.io/blog/2019/05/15/spring-data-r2dbc-1-0-m2-and-spring-boot-starter-released) I have to add also `io.r2dbc:r2dbc-pool`
and use `spring.r2dbc.pool.*` properties to configure pooling.

Also, according to [this reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html#spring.r2dbc.pool.enabled) I do not need to turn on pooling manually because SB will enable it if `r2dbc-pool` is found on the classpath.

Is it enough or do I miss something?

Comment: Have you tried it? If so what didn't work.

Comment: Yes! And the application works. However, I can't be sure that the connection pool is really used. Is there maybe some specific logs that I may spot? Or any other way to verify this?

Comment: If you added the dependency there is a pool, with defaults, which you can override through the `spring.r2dbc.pool` properties. As explained in the documentation.

Comment: Can you please point out where is it explained in the documentation? Also I just spotted that the dependency `io.r2dbc:r2dbc-pool` comes already as a transitive dependency from `spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc:2.3.5.REALEASE` meaning that actually I do not need to declare it explicitly (This can also be seen here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc/2.3.5.RELEASE)

Comment: This section explains that it is configured based on the URL (you will need that) everything else is optional.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Answering my own question.

TLDR

- Having `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc:2.3.5.RELEASE` is enough to have connection pooling enabled by default
- No need to add `io.r2dbc:r2dbc-postgresql` explicitly
- No need to put `:pool:` in the URL in this case

Some detailed findings.
it seems there are two ways to enable connection pool:

1. Put `:pool:` driver chunk into the URL and then `io.r2dbc.pool.PoolingConnectionFactoryProvider#create` will take care of creating a Connection Pool. This is described at https://github.com/r2dbc/r2dbc-pool#getting-started
2. Do not have `spring.r2dbc.pool.enabled=false` in configs (meaning that its absence is interpreted as `true` by default). This way a Connection Pool will be created by the `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.r2dbc.ConnectionFactoryConfigurations.Pool#connectionFactory`. I am not sure, but it looks like a generalized Spring Boot configuration-style override over a library specific `:pool:` option.

This options are independent and partly overlap and the second one takes precedence.

The second component evaluates also presence of the `:pool:` in the URL (see `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.r2dbc.ConnectionFactoryConfigurations.PooledConnectionFactoryCondition`)
and if found it delegates the creation of the Connection Pool to the first one.

There is also a peculiar conclusion - having explicit `spring.r2dbc.pool.enabled=false` leads to creation of a Connection Pool anyway if there is a `:pool:` in the URL. Therefore the only way to disable pooling is to have `spring.r2dbc.pool.enabled=false` and to omit `:pool:` in the URL at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked for me

```
String url = "r2dbc:postgres://user:password@hostname:5432/testdb?ApplicationName=myapp";
ConnectionFactory ret= ConnectionFactories.get(url);

ConnectionPoolConfiguration poolConfiguration = ConnectionPoolConfiguration.builder(ret)
                .initialSize(5)                        .maxSize(10).maxIdleTime(Duration.ofMinutes(5)).build();

ConnectionPool pool = new ConnectionPool(poolConfiguration);

return pool;
```